# Trying to calcuate mean and std using float32 numpy arrays. Getting float64 returned

Tags: python, numpy

[EDIT]

Okay my test case was poorly thought out.  I only tested on 1-D arrays.  in which case I get a 64bit scalar returned. If I do it on 3D array, I get the 32 bit as expected.

I am trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a very large numpy array (600*600*4044) and I am close to the limit of my memory (16GB on a 64bit machine).  As such I am trying to process everything as a float32 rather than the float64 that is the default.  However, any time I try to work on the data I get a float64 returned even if I specify the dtype as float32.  why is this happening?  Yes I can convert afterwards, but like I said I am close the to limit of my RAM and I am trying to keep everything as small as possible even during the processing step.  Below is an example of what I am getting.

```
import scipy
a = scipy.ones((600,600,4044), dtype=scipy.float32)
print(a.dtype)

a_mean = scipy.mean(a, 2, dtype=scipy.float32)
a_std = scipy.std(a, 2, dtype=scipy.float32)

print(a_mean.dtype)
print(a_std.dtype)
```

Returns

```
float32
float32
float32
```

Comment: Would be so much easier just to switch to 64 bit Python

Comment: Why?  I don't see how that would help.

Comment: Because then you would not be limited to 32 bit address space. That's what I expect is the real limit, rather than the physical RAM.

Comment: How would that use less memory?

Comment: It would not use less memory. But it would allow your process to use more memory. I'm hypothesising that the actual limit is address space rather than physical RAM. Am I wrong? How much physical RAM does the machine have? Is the machine a 64 bit system?

Comment: The problem is that am storing data an a 600*600*4044 numpy array.  I have machine with 16Gb of ram.  At 64bit precision it takes up about 11.5GB or ram.  I don't need that level of precision, so at 32bit it should take up 5.7(ish)GB or RAM. If I can force it to use float32.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get all the arrays as `float32`.

Comment: @tiago That's what my answer says. The original version of the code was different and did produce the output that Caustic claimed. Have a look at the question edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: *This answer applied to the original question*

You have to switch to 64 bit Python. According to your comments your object has size 5.7GB even with 32 bit floats. That cannot fit in 32 bit address space which is 4GB, at best.

Once you've switched to 64 bit Python I think you can stop worrying about intermediate values using 64 bit floats. In fact you can quite probably perform your entire calculation using 64 bit floats.

If you are already using 64 bit Python (and your comments confused me on the matter), then you simply do not need to worry about `scipy.mean` or `scipy.std` returning a 64 bit float. That's one single value out of ~1.5 billion values in your array. It's nothing to worry about.

**Note**: *This answer applies to the new question*

The code in your question produces the following output:

```
float32
float32
float32
```

In other words, the symptoms that you report are not in fact representative of reality. The reason for the confusion is that you earlier code, that to which my original answer applied, was quite different and operated on a single dimensional array. It looks awfully like `scipy` returns scalars as `float64`. But when the return value is not a scalar, then the data type is not transformed in the way you thought.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  But I don't think you understand my problem.  I am using 64bit Python.  I am not trying to fit my array into 32bit address space.  I am merely trying to conserve the memory that I do have.  11.5Gb is too big, not because I don't have the room to process it just now.  But because I still have more stuff I want to load.  Also there is the memory from the OS taking up room.

Comment: hmm, the OP wants 32bit float as the base value, but the array itself can be adress by a 64bit pointer.

Comment: Your comment above "Why? I don't see how that would help." indicated that you were using 32 bit Python. These intermediate values are not a problem.

Comment: @georgesl The OP has got 32 bit float. So what if `scipy.mean` returns a 64 bit float. That's 4 bytes out of 5.7GB.

Comment: @Caustic Whilst I think you have nothing to worry about, I do also wonder why scipy converts from 32 bit to 64 bit. It clearly performs all the calcs at 32 bit and then right at the end converts back to 64 bit. Odd.

Comment: No, it is not.  numpy uses element by element calculation (like Matlab) so it returns 1455840000 data points at 64bit. hence the 11.5 GB.  Try it your self.  try import scipy.  scipy.zeros(1455840000) and watch your computer fill its RAM

Comment: In the code in the question, `a_mean` is a scalar, with value 1. You are not doing `scipy.zeros(1455840000)`. Also, you are doing `scipy.zeros(1455840000, dtype=scipy.float32)`.

Comment: Just to clarify scipy.mean(scipy.zeros(600,600,4044), 2)) returns an array that is 600*600.  That is the average through the z direction

Comment: @Caustic Yes, I'm looking at the code in the question. Would you like to change the question so that I can change my answer? FWIW, a 600*600 float64 bit array is still insignificant compared to the main object.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to change the base type :

```
a_mean = numpy.ndarray( scipy.mean(a, dtype=scipy.float32) , dtype = scipy.float32 )
```

I have tested it, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

There is a `out` option :  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

```
a = scipy.ones(10, dtype=scipy.float32)
b = numpy.array(0,dtype=scipy.float32)

scipy.mean(a, dtype=scipy.float32, out=b)
```

Test :

```
In [34]: b= numpy.array(0)

In [35]: b= numpy.array(0,dtype = scipy.float32)

In [36]: b.dtype
Out[36]: dtype('float32')

In [37]: scipy.mean(a, dtype=scipy.float32, out = numpy.array(b) )                                                       
Out[37]: 1.0

In [38]: b
Out[38]: array(0.0, dtype=float32)

In [39]:
```

Comment: From the question "Yes I can convert afterwards" so I guess Caustic knows how to do this.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet.  I think that this will still make the very large array (11.5GB) and then convert it.  so at some point in the execution it will max my memory.  That is why I am avoiding converting and would like to force numpy to do it all using 32bit natively.

Comment: @Caustic numpy already does do it all 32 bit natively! I suggest you execute the code in your question and compare the output you see with the output that you claim.

Comment: Okay thanks David.  They code I have posted does return float32.  However my other much more complex code returns as I originally posted. I need to go back and take another look at it as clearly I have made a different error somewhere. Yes I know numpy does 32 natively.  Poorly phrased by me I meant I didn't want it to return 64 and then convert to 32 as that would not solve my issue.